# flask jquery html form returning None for Image

Tags: python, api, flask, file-upload, python-requests

New to web development, and trying to do a simple upload of an image, the goal is to get in in s3.  But currently When i select a photo and submit the request comes back as none, cant figure out why.

**html form**

```
<form name="update_profile_image_form" id="update_profile_image_form" class="text-center mt-2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display: block;" action="/user/update/profile-image/">
  <input type="file" class="form-control-file form-control-file-sm ml-3 mt-2" id="profile_image" name="profile_image" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit" value="Update" class="form-control-file form-control-file-sm ml-2 mt-2 text-center btn btn-sm btn-info" style="width: 90%;"></input>
</form>
```

**script**

```
$("form[name=update_profile_image_form").submit(function(e) {

  var $form = $(this);
  var $error = $form.find(".error");
  var data = $form.serialize();

  $.ajax({
      url: "/user/update/profile_image",
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp) {
        window.location.href = "/account/";
        
      }
    });
  
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

**route**

```
@app.route('/user/update/profile_image', methods=['POST'])
def update_profile_image(): 
  return User().update_profile_image()
```

**function**

```
  def update_profile_image(self):
    img = request.files.get('profile_image')
    print(img)
    
    return redirect(url_for('account'))
```

also tried `img = request.form.get('profile_image')`

No Error, the `print(img)` comes back as none

the goal is to upload the image, pass to the function, assign it a uuid and upload to s3, Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot serialize an image and send it as json.

You should use a [form data object](https://javascript.info/formdata). However, print(img) will not work as you cannot print an image in this way.

Alternatively you could pass the image as a string by [converting it to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript).